# how not to insert more than two sequential nextval value?

Tags: spring, oracle, insert, sequence

I'm using spring framework and oracle DB for the Web solution system.

The problem is when I call the web page related on oracle sequence,
sometimes more than two rows are inserted on the DB table.

That rows has not duplicated values but increased values from sequence.
Also I already checked the java code, 
but I didn't use the loop or for sentences or call twice insert sentences.

Is that occurred often?
and how can I solve the problem?

Do I have to add the code for checking value or make the oracle trigger on the table?

This is the code.

```
    public void insertDefaultLParameter(HttpServletRequest request, String workflowId) throws Exception{
        String newLParaId =  mapper.getNewLParaId();

        HashMap<String, String> condition = new HashMap<String, String>();
        condition.put("newLParaId", newLParaId);
        condition.put("paraValue", "2013-05");
        condition.put("workflowId", workflowId);

        mapper.insertLParameter(condition);
        mapper.insertLParameterMapping(condition);
    }
```

> "getNewLParaId()" called the sequence "MT_L_PARA_MAPPING_SEQ" like the below sql.

```
SELECT 'LPARA'  || LPAD(MT_L_PARA_MAPPING_SEQ.nextval,10,0) FROM DUAL
```

> After getting the value, the value is inserted into two tables through "insertLParameter" and "insertLParameterMapping" mapping id.
>
> And the below is the code which call "insertDefaultLParameter" class.
>
> See the bottom of the code.
>
> You can find "rfmService.insertDefaultLParameter(request, praWfId);".

```
@RequestMapping(value="/insertWorkflowInfo", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public ModelAndView insertWorkflowDetail(Locale locae, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");  
        String userId = user.getUserId();


        String workflowNm = "";
        String alsPpsCd = "";
        String workflowDesc = "";
        String pid = "";
        String plevel = "";

        if(request.getParameter("workflowNm") != null || !request.getParameter("workflowNm").equals("")) workflowNm = request.getParameter("workflowNm");   
        if(request.getParameter("alsPpsCd") != null || !request.getParameter("alsPpsCd").equals("")) alsPpsCd = request.getParameter("alsPpsCd");   
        if(request.getParameter("workflowDesc") != null || !request.getParameter("workflowDesc").equals("")) workflowDesc = request.getParameter("workflowDesc");   
        if(request.getParameter("pid") != null || !request.getParameter("pid").equals("")) pid = request.getParameter("pid");   
        if(request.getParameter("plevel") != null || !request.getParameter("plevel").equals("")) plevel = request.getParameter("plevel");   


        //0. 
        //HashMap<String,String> treeMgtInfo = new HashMap<String,String>();
        //treeMgtInfo.put("treeId",pid);

        // 
        HashMap<String,String> input = new HashMap<String,String>();

        //2. 
        String praWfId = wfService.selectPraWfid();
        input.put("praWfId", praWfId);
        input.put("wfNm",workflowNm);
        input.put("wfDesc", SecurityUtil.removeXSS(workflowDesc));
        input.put("alsPpsCd",alsPpsCd);
        input.put("usrId",userId);
        input.put("rgUsrId",userId);

        // 1. 
        wfService.insertWorkflowDetail(input);


        input.put("treeNm",workflowNm);

        // 
        int treeLevCd = new Integer(plevel) +1 ;
        input.put("treeLevCd",""+treeLevCd);
        input.put("treeBjCd",Constant.TREE_BJ_CD_WORKFLOW);
        input.put("treeCd",Constant.TREE_CD_WORKFLOW);
        // 
        input.put("treeLrkRufId",praWfId);
        input.put("upTreeId",pid);

        //  
        int sceXrsSeqVl = treeService.selectSceXrsSeqId(input);     
        input.put("sceXrsSeqVl",""+sceXrsSeqVl);

        String treeId = treeService.selectTreeIdInfo();
        input.put("treeId",treeId);
        // 2.  
        rfmService.insertDefaultLParameter(request, praWfId);
        // 3. 
        treeService.insertTreeMgtInfoWithId(input);

        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView("defaultViews");
        modelAndView.addObject("treeId",treeId);
        modelAndView.addObject("praWfId",praWfId);

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

This is all of code related on the sequence.

Comment: an unique constraint on those columns help you?

Comment: The problem ought to be solved by ensuring that only one insert is made. Adding a constraint could be good, but would result in constraint violation if multiple inserts are made.

Comment: In my opinion, sometimes your page is called twice that triggers next value fetch from the sequence, you need to check why that statement is called twice if so and which event is responsible for it. Or may be at each refresh of the page, the sequence statement is being called.

Comment: I'm sorry but this does not have enough details to help you. There could be any number of reasons for this happening. This most likely, as had been said, is that you're just doing it twice. However, without any code no one can check.

Comment: You should probably address the problem at both ends: (1) Find out why your application is sometimes doing the insert twice; (2) Add a UNIQUE constraint on a business key in the table so that in the event of the application trying to insert twice, it fails.

Comment: @TonyAndrews The column already has Primary Key constraints.

Comment: @OracleUser No, it doesn't help. Really strange..

Comment: Yes, but a primary key based on a sequence is no protection against duplicate rows, as you are finding! However, an additional unique key on some columns that should be unique would be.